# Flex div not resize by content

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

Here is example as it should work:

```css
*{
  border: solid 1px blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
/*   padding: 0; */
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.middle{
  background: gray;
  width: 500px;
}
.footer {
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="middle">
    <div>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</div>
    <div>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</div>
    <div>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</div>
    <div>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</div>
    <div>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</div>
    <div>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</div>
    <div>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</div>
    <div>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  Footer 
</footer>
```

And it work, but only in jsfiddle example and in firefox, but in Chrome it looks like this:

[image: Chrome result]

But jsfiddle example was tested in Chrome. Can anyone help me?

Comment: which version you are using?,I can't reproduce this error on chrome

Comment: Chrome version is 55.0.2883.87

Comment: Change HTML height to auto it might be restricting, or setting overflow:auto inside HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer:

**flex: 1;**
This is the shorthand for **flex-grow, flex-shrink** and **flex-basis** combined. The second and third parameters (flex-shrink and flex-basis) are optional. Default is **0 1 auto**.

Using **flex-grow: 1;** instead of **flex: 1;** resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing width from middle

```
*{
  border: solid 1px blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
/*   padding: 0; */
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.middle{
  background: gray;
 }
.footer {
}
```

Comment: Still the same, but now it with content width. But I need resize height by content.